# Nest.js and Jest testing framework: Can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard in the RootTestModule context

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am using Jest framework for testing my Nest.js application. Here is the `recovery.controller.spec.ts` file:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { RecoveryController } from './recovery.controller';

describe('RecoveryController', () => {
  let controller: RecoveryController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [RecoveryController]
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<RecoveryController>(RecoveryController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Right now, when I am executing this test, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

And honestly, I just cannot fix it. Application works perfectly fine and I have no error with both controller and service. I have been trying to add `RecoveryService` to both provides and imports of this module, but it did not help. Also, when I add `RecoveryService` to the list of provides, the error message changes to the following:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RecoveryService (?, CryptographicService, UsersService). Please make sure that the argument ConfirmationHashService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

Could anyone please explain me where is the error? Below I am going to provide the source code of the related modules and services if this might be helpful:

**recovery.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  controllers: [RecoveryController],
  providers: [RecoveryService],
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ApiConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.jwtAuthConfig.secret
      }),
      inject: [ApiConfigService]
    }),
    ConfirmationHashModule,
    UsersModule
  ]
})
export class RecoveryModule {}
```

Constructor of the `recovery.service.ts`:

```
constructor(
  private readonly confirmationHashService: ConfirmationHashService,
  private readonly cryptographicService: CryptographicService,
  private readonly usersService: UsersService
) {}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
    forwardRef(() => RolesModule),
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([Session, UserSettings]),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ApiConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.jwtAuthConfig.secret
      }),
      inject: [ApiConfigService]
    })
  ],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Constructor of the `auth.service.ts`:

```
constructor(
  private readonly cryptographicService: CryptographicService,
  private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  private readonly configService: ApiConfigService,
  private readonly phoneService: PhoneService,
  private readonly timeService: TimeService,
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => RolesService))
  private readonly rolesService: RolesService,
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => EmailService))
  private readonly emailService: EmailService,
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => UsersService))
  private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  @InjectModel(Session) private readonly sessionRepository: typeof Session
) {}
```

Thanks everyone for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to mock AuthGuard and RecoveryService

```
 const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [RecoveryController],
      providers: [RecoveryService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(RecoveryService)
      .useValue(mockRecoveryService)
      .overrideGuard(AuthGuard)
      .useValue({ canActivate: jest.fn(() => true) })
      .compile();

export const mockRecoveryService= {
  recoveryServiceMethod: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return ;
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the module you have created in the test spec file only has a reference to your controller - any dependencies of that controller need to be mocked.

What you probably want (At least for the AuthGuard) is

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [RecoveryController]
})
.overrideGuard(AuthGuard)
.useValue({ canActivate: jest.fn(() => true) })
.compile();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Don't you meanwhile know why after that I have this second error message? Here is the message: `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RecoveryService (?, CryptographicService, UsersService). Please make sure that the argument ConfirmationHashService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.`

Comment: That's what I figured would be the next thing. 
You want to use .overrideProvider for the ConfirmationHashService